# Kotlin how to I specify that I want a specific readLine()?

Tags: kotlin

How to I specify that I want a specific `readLine()`?

```
cat >so.kt <<EOF
fun readLine():String{return "5"}
fun main() {
print("Enter an Integer value: ") 
var an_int = readLine()?.toInt()  
    println("Which readLine() -- an_int: \$an_int")
    }
EOF
kscript so.kt 
Enter an Integer value: Which readLine() -- an_int: 5
```

Comment: In addition to clarifying the mention of Scanner (as per my answer), please note that not everyone has kscript; if you could update the question to use kotlinc instead, it would be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use the fully-qualified name of the function.

Normally, an unqualified call to:

```
    readLine()
```

would refer to [`kotlin.io.readLine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html).  (`kotlin.io` is one of the packages that's [imported by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports).)  But if there's a local `readLine()` function in scope, as here, then it would refer to that instead.

However, if you qualify it:

```
    kotlin.io.readLine()
```

then you get the stdlib one as specified.  This is a general principle that works with classnames too (in Java as well as Kotlin): unqualified names can be ambiguous, but fully-qualified ones aren't<sup>*</sup>.

(Also note that it won't compile if you just make that change; the stdlib function can return null (if if hits end-of-stream), and so you'll need to handle that.)

<sup>(<sup>*</sup> Though, since there's no way to further qualify classes and functions in the default package, those can still cause trouble.  That's why it's best to put your code in a named package.)</sup>